# AWS application load balancer - redirect non-www to https://www

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-application-load-balancer

I have deployed my application on **EC2 - ubuntu 18.04 (Apache server)**. I registered this EC2 with an **Application Load Balancer**, I want to redirect **non-www** traffic to https://www.mydomain.co

When I type **[www.mydomain.co](http://www.mydomain.co)** in browser, it redirects to https://www.mydomain.co  which is working fine.
But when I type without www that is only **mydomain.co** then it shows "This site can’t be reached".

Following are the rules I defined in ALB -

[image]

Can anyone help please?

Comment: This is for port 80, have you checked your 443 listener will serve this hostname?

Comment: I didn't write any rule for 443, it is same as by default.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be done on the **domain level**, not on the load balancer.

If you use Route53, then you should create a new ALIAS record `mydomain.co` which points to the URL of your load balancer. Or a record redirecting `mydomain.co` to `www.mydomain.co`.

This way both `mydomain.co` and `www.mydomain.co` will be directed to the ALB.

If you don't use Route53, similar operation should be performed on your domain registrar.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response, I've already added ALIAS  record set in Route53

Comment: @SachinVairagi Hi. You had it from the beginning? Your question does not mention it, or you just added now? And what is the outcome?

Comment: I had it from the beginning but just added a new ALIAS without www and it is working now, thanks a lot.

Comment: @SachinVairagi Thanks and no problem. Glad it worked out.

Comment: I would suggest the first line here should say something like *"Configuration is required at the DNS level as well as in the load balancer,"* since configuration in the load balancer or some other entity that speaks HTTP is still needed.

Comment: Possibly useful: it isn't quite right to redirect straight from `http://example.com` → `https://www.example.com` in a single step. It "works" but really needs to be done in two steps to avoid false browser detection of malicious behavior: ***either*** `http://example.com` → `https://example.com` → `https://www.example.com` (upgrade the existing authority to use https, then change the host) ***or*** (not as good as the prior option but should still work) `http://example.com` → `http://www.example.com` → `https://www.example.com` (change the host while still in HTTP mode, then upgrade to HTTPS).

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Thank you. I will remember these options.

Answer (score 0):

I am try the config the same setting,
on Route53, I have 2 (A) records both pointed to the alb server

```
domain.com -> ALB DNS Name
www.domain.com -> ALB DNS Name
```

You have 2 listeners on ALB Port 80 and 443

on port 80, use 301 redirects to `All traffic` to HTTPS (Port 443)

on Port 443, points the destination to your desired webserver

[config listener](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QJHfB.png)

[config https handler](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vq8H9.png)